# Does firebase have a way to call my code every two weeks? Scheduling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, firebase

I'm looking to update my table automatically every two weeks. And I want my function to get called by firebase.

Is this possible?

I'm using angular 2 typescript with firebase.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good way to realize cronejobs only with firebase. But you can use a third-party service like [zapier](https://zapier.com/app/explore?services=FirebaseDevAPI) to realize scheduled tasks.

Comment: Do you know any other light weight third party tools

Comment: I dont know other tools with a good firebase integration. But maybe another way is ro run crone job on your own aws instance (or on another server).

Comment: Not sure how to do that

Comment: Il have a look at zapier

Comment: Would this work in the app.ts file http://www.willmaster.com/blog/javascript/javascript-setinterval.php

Comment: @AngularM  JavaScript functions are supported by typescript, however this is not an ideal way to do it. cronjob will be better choice then this